# Nginx and its caching systems. Are they all the same?

Tags: nginx, cache, memcached, page-speed

I'm a bit confuse about PageSpeed, Microcaching and Memcached. Are they just different tools that do the same job?

I was initially thinking in use PageSpeed with Nginx. If I do that, do I need microcaching? And how about memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Microcaching: A technology to cache quasi-static but dynamically generated content for a very short time (order of seconds). This helps only if you have multiple requests per this interval.
- PageSpeed: A group of technologies implemented as a web server module that try to speed up the web site with optimizations like load order changing, JS and CSS minifying/compressing, image resizing/compressing, caching and various other filters. In contrast to microcaching, it actively changes the content delivered to the client.
- Memcache is a general purpose RAM caching system that is used for many different purposes. It  can be used as a caching backend at least for PageSpeed.

You can use microcaching and PageSpeed together, but you have to test if it actually helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about Varnish too if you're looking for real speed. A bit over my head to implement (I'm happy with memcache though), but something you might like to look into.

Also, my experience with JS and CSS minifying and compressing isn't so good. Styling tends to break when I'm trying to config it.